# How many dimensions can be embedded within a small number of dimensions

Tags: vector-spaces

I was wondering how many dimensions can be embedded within a 2D space, or more generally within N-dimensions. Is there a formal demonstration?

This question came to me when I read about the [Holographic principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle), it says is possible to encode a volume inside a black hole into the area that surrounds it. So there is a one to one correspondence between 3D and 2D.

Comment: I am not sure the tag vector-space is appropriate for this question. It might be better to pose this question on physics SE, too.

Comment: @Fabian The Holographic principle is just an exemplification.

Comment: You should have clarified what you mean with embedding. The holographic principle conserves some notion of locality.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Abelian group $(\mathbb R,+)$ is isomorphic to that of $(\mathbb R^k,+)$, for any finite $k$, and in fact even more.

It follows that a single dimension can encode infinitely many dimensions.